# Python: SSHTunnel and Socks5 server

Tags: python, selenium, ssh, proxy, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying for the last couple of hours to find a solution of tunneling a SSH connection and create a Socks5 server on that SSH tunnel, so I can browse a webpage with Selenium.
For connecting to remote SSH, I've been using [sshtunnel](https://github.com/pahaz/sshtunnel/). I managed to connect to the remote SSH server. Now I'm trying to create a SOCKS5 server on that connection so I can use it with FireFox.
I'm exhausted, have been searching for at least 4 hours and no result. 
What should I look for? Did anyone create a Socks5 server from a SSH Tunnel?

Comment: I'm still googling to find the right thing. I cannot find anything related to this, just a github comment that says it can't be done...

Comment: you need provide more detail like network setup, web server address etc.